Call command-line from within AnyLogic
I have a non-java app that I need to be calling from within AnyLogic. The app requires a text file where the input parameter value are stored. The same process in MATLAB would look like:
md = system([app_folder 'HM autostart ' txt_file_name]);
where app_folder is the path to the folder that contains the app called HM,
and txt_file_name is the name of the text that contains the input values for the app to run.
Thank you.
I have tried using the Runtime.getRuntime() approach, but it doesn't work for this specific app, so decided to apply the command line approach that works well in MATLAB.
